# Bulk rename Excel 2010 files based on each file's B4 cell content

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a folder with over 2000+ MS Excel 2010 `.XLSX` spreadsheets and I need to perform the following actions:

1. I need to open each individual file
2. Copy the content of cell `B4` (+ each file has unique content on cell `B4`), and
3. append the content of cell `B4` to the original file name

I am using  Ansgar Wiechers' code below, and it seems to be working.

Thank you so much.

Trying to learn and tight dead lines are not a great match :)

Comment: What is not working? What is your _real_ question? What have you done to the above code to try and make it work for you?

Comment: editted my post with a proper question and sample edits. thank you Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the code you're trying to adopt is designed to operate on a single file. The `Open()` method does not support wildcards in the path.

```
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\...")   # open the file
# ...
# do stuff 
# ...
$a = Release-Ref($wb)                # release the reference to the workbook
```

So the first thing you need to do is put a loop around that section and feed it with the output of `Get-ChildItem`. If you want `Get-ChildItem` to start at a particular path you need to specify that path via the `-Path` parameter, otherwise it will start in the current working directory.

```
$root = 'C:\some\folder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.xlsx' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
  # ...
  # do stuff
  # ...
  $a = Release-Ref($wb)
}
```

Make sure to leave the handling of the Excel application object *outside* the loop.

Extract the value of cell B4:

```
$b4 = $wb.Sheets.Item(1).Cells.Item(4, 2).Value
```

and append it to the file name:

```
$newname = $_.BaseName + $b4 + $_.Extension
```

If `.Value` doesn't return the actual value in that cell, try `.Text` instead.

Before you can rename the file you need to close it first. However, the `Release-Ref` function only releases the reference you have to an object. It doesn't close the workbook (or the application for that matter). You need to do that yourself:

```
$root = 'C:\some\folder'
Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.xlsx' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
  # ...
  # do stuff
  # ...
  $wb.Close()                        # actually close the file
  $a = Release-Ref($wb)
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
}
```

Comment: Thank Ansgar,I tried piecing you code together and it runs but: 1.- it wants to go through ALL the files in the drive. 2.- I am not able to rename any of the files.

Comment: @HGtez Your code didn't actually close the workbooks (sorry, didn't pay close enough attention to what `Release-Ref` does - or rather does not do). Also, you need to tell `Get-ChildItem` where to start from, otherwise it'll start from the current working directory. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, I tried your code and updated my original post with the new results.

Comment: @HGtez Try using `.Text` instead of `.Value`. Also, your updated code is not what I suggested. Please read my answer again.